# AD Query, Server is not operational

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

So, I have this method, and in the last line, where it tried to get samAccountName, its throwing me a COM Exception which is making me crazy.

Any idea?

```
public User FindUsername(string samAccountName, string groupDisplayName)   
        {
            using (DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(ldapf, ldapu, ldapp))
            {
                using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot))
                {               
                    searcher.Asynchronous = false;
                    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName");
                    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
                    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uSNChanged");
                    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
                    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("co");
                    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("company");
                    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");


                    searcher.Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", samAccountName);
                    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                    searcher.PageSize = 1000;

                    SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
                    ResultPropertyCollection resultPropColl = result.Properties;
                    Object memberColl = resultPropColl["member"];
                    using (DirectoryEntry memberEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + memberColl, ldapu, ldapp))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection userprops = memberEntry.Properties;
                            object obVal = userprops["SAMAccountName"].Value;
```

Comment: Server is not operational COMException.

Comment: Check your properties, SAMAccountName should be sAMAccountName (Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679635(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I have the same code running fine in a timer service in sharepoint 2010, exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe the DomainController is down? (Link: http://weblogs.asp.net/pabloperalta/archive/2011/12/22/dynamics-crm-comexception-the-server-is-not-operational.aspx)

Comment: What format is ldapf in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a problem with my code that was working somewhere else and I was missing a foreach

```
foreach (Object memberColl in resultPropColl["member"])
                    {
```

Apparently if it returns one user, resultPropColl["member"] is still a collection of objects?